# Programmatically get a list of all fields?

Tags: 7, entities, log-messages

How to retrieve a list of fields, similar to what is available at `admin/reports/fields`, but so that I can have them in an array that I can stuff in a select dropdown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [field_info_fields()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_fields/7), which returns an array containing information about all the defined fields. Its output is similar to the following one.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What tools did you use to display the array in this format? :)

Comment: You can use the Devel module from http://www.drupal.org/project/devel

eg in a custom module `dpm(field_get_fields());`. Devel also has a Fields information block where it lists out basically the same information as the above 1 line of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [field_info_field_map()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.info.inc/function/field_info_field_map/7.x) it returns a lightweight map of fields across bundles. [field_info_fields()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.info.inc/function/field_info_fields/7.x) also return fields list but its document suggesting us **"Use of this function should be avoided when possible, since it loads and statically caches a potentially large array of information.".**

The function only returns active, non deleted fields.

$field_list = field_info_field_map();

dsm($field_list);

[image]